# Enitty Framework - How to call a SELECT procedure on an entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In as the title says, I want to call a stored procedure in order to select a table that is mapped into my entity.

For example, in `Dataset`, you could replace the select for a stored procedure, which allowed me to select 1 or all rows in the table, or even more logic, specified by the parameters.

Example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectProjects]
    (@Id AS INTEGER = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        T.[Id], 
        T.[ProjectName]
    FROM
        [dbo].[Projects] AS T
    WHERE
        T.[Id] = ISNULL(@Id, T.[Id]) -- If NULL, selects all rows, else selects specified row
END
```

I'm aware I can call the procedure with entity, however, it will return a list of rows that are typed from the procedure. I do not what that, since I want results that are part of my entity model (`Projects`).

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/cud-stored-procedures

Comment: I'm doing database first approach.

Comment: Not reason you can't modify the model that gets created from the database to add enhancements like using a stored procedure.

Comment: You can set the return type of the stored procedure to an entity type when you edit the function import.

Comment: I was aware of that, but I think the entities returned by the procedure won't be the same as those in my table. I would have to match them with my primary key. Is that correct ?